# Solr exact match regarding words number

Tags: solr, exact-match

I've been looking for a week already for some working solution that will allow the following:

Documents: [phrase:"cat"], [phrase:"pussy cat"], [phrase:"cats"]

Search query: "cat" => results: "cat", "cats" (*but not "pussy cat"*)

Search query: "cats" => results: "cats", "cat" (*but not "pussy cat"*)

I saw several suggestions on the Web on how to achieve this. [Somewhere](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-do-exact-match-tp4014264p4014362.html) I saw a suggestion to insert marker tokens at the beginning and end of the field values when indexing, and then do "phrase queries" that include those marker tokens. [In other place](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Match-all-terms-in-doc-td504272.html) I saw a suggestion to calculate number of unique terms in each document.

I find the second suggestion (*with calculating words*) is a quite complicated, and I cannot recognize on how to use the first suggestion.

So the question is could you give a hint on how to implement "exact match regarding requested words number and using stemming (word forms)" in Solr?

Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have solved the problem as follows (*with prefixes and suffixes*):

in solrconfig.xml:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="exact"> 
    <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="source">phrase</str>
        <str name="dest">phraseExact</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldName">phraseExact</str>
        <str name="pattern">^(.*)$</str>
        <str name="replacement">_prefix_ $1 _suffix_</str>
        <bool name="literalReplacement">false</bool>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
<!-- other contents of solrconfig.xml... -->
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="update.chain">exact</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

in schema.xml:

```
<field name="phrase" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="phraseExact" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

After the changes it is needed to restart Solr instance then re-index (re-add) all the documents.

Now we have documents like this:

```
{
    "phrase": "test",
    "id": "9c95fac2ed78149c",
    "phraseExact": "_prefix_ test _suffix_",
    "_version_": 1471599816879374300
 },
 {
    "phrase": "test phrase",
    "id": "9c95fac2ed78123c",
    "phraseExact": "_prefix_ test phrase _suffix_",
    "_version_": 1471599816123474300
 },
```

If search the documents by queries like

```
"q=phraseExact:"_prefix_ test _suffix_"
"q=phraseExact:"_prefix_ testing _suffix_"
"q=phraseExact:"_prefix_ tests _suffix_"
```

We will only receive the {"phrase":"test"} document (and not {"phrase":"test phrase"})