# Need exact matches in solr search results

Tags: solr, exact-match

Currently, I am facing the following small problem while doing exact search (query enclosed within double quotes).

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "q": "\"sale\"",
      "indent": "true",
      "fl": "displayValue, categoryName, approved, averageRating, lastOneWeekCount, connectorName, score",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1579279511471"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 918,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 11.044312,
    "docs": [
      {
        "displayValue": "Net Sales  Vs Contribution Margin",
        "categoryName": "Sales Analytics (B07)",
        "connectorName": "New BOBJ",
        "lastOneWeekCount": 3,
        "approved": "yes",
        "averageRating": 4,
        "score": 11.044312
      },
```

The above "sale" query is matching against "Sales" term in the indexed data, which is not exact. Also this is happening because of the EdgeNgramFilterFactory that is in the defined text field (which uses whitespace tokenizer). 
I have managed to incrementally resolve different search issues with the current implementation of select request handler and now I need to solve the above problem of exact match. Following is my solrconfig details.

```
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="exact">false</str>
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="qf">
         displayValue^20 description^5 connectorName_txt zenDescription_txt^5 zenBusinessOwner_txt^2 
         categoryName^8 reportOwner^2 reportDetailsNameColumn^5 
      </str>
      <str name="pf2">
         displayValue^20 description^5 connectorName_txt zenDescription_txt^5 zenBusinessOwner_txt^2 
         categoryName^8 reportOwner^2 reportDetailsNameColumn^5 
      </str>
      <str name="pf3">
         displayValue^20 description^5 connectorName_txt zenDescription_txt^5 zenBusinessOwner_txt^2 
         categoryName^8 reportOwner^2 reportDetailsNameColumn^5 
      </str>
      <str name="tie">1</str>
      <str name="mm">100%</str>
      <int name="ps2">3</int>
      <int name="ps3">9</int>
      <int name="qs">0</int>
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
      <str name="sort">score desc, averageRating desc, lastOneWeekCount desc</str>
      <str name="bq">
        query({!boost b=20}approved:"yes")
      </str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="appends">
      <str name="fq">{!switch case.false='*:*' case.true='text_ex:$q' v=$exact}</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

In the above config details, I have attempted to solve the exact search problem by adding an extra switch case query parser in the config (after searching the net). Basically, I want to implement exact search if user input query has double quotes. I wanted to implement exact search when user specifies exact=true using the switch query parser. But I am kind of stuck as I am not getting any results.
Can someone please help?

P.S Attaching the schema definition as well. Please check.

```
<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
        <analyzer type="index" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false">  
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />    
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer> 
        <analyzer type="query"> 
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" /> 
        </analyzer> 
    </fieldType>


    <fieldType name="text_exact" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
        <analyzer type="index" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false">  
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" 
            catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />    
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer> 
        <analyzer type="query"> 
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" 
            catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer> 
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: Could you include the definition of the field that you are searching on? (is it text_ex?)

Comment: Updated the question with the requested details. Please check.

Answer (score 3):

Using double quotes does not mean *exact*. It only allows you to make phrase queries where the terms have to appear after each other. Solr (Lucene) searches against the *tokens* you've generated.

Use a field with a specific definition that does not change the tokens (i.e. no ngrams, no stemming, etc). If you only want to match the whole field exactly (but case insensitive), use a `KeywordTokenizer` with a `LowercaseFilter`. If you only want case sensitive, exact hits for the whole field, use a `string` field.

If you want exact matches against each term, use a tokenizer with the behavior you're after, and pick filters to normalize case (i.e. to make it case insensitive) or not. You then decide which field to query based on whether the user is asking for an exact search or not.

You're going to have to determine how `"foo" bar` should behave and how `"foo bar" baz` should behave as well.

Comment: Many people consider double quoted search as exact match search and so does my client. I need to extend the solr functionality of treating double quote search as phrase queries (with query slop zero for me), to term queries as well. Please find the updated question with schema definition, because even after `KeywordTokenizer` was included, it didn't help solve the exact match problem. Also, as of now, my clientele searches are limited to either searching with double quotes or without them, so I don't have to think about mixed queries. Please help.

Comment: Your word delimiter factory is still going to split text based on rules (for example split on `-`). Could you add an example of what you've indexed, and what your complete query looks like?

Comment: For example if I search for `"sale"` solr should return exact matches of the term `sale` but it is returning matches for `Sales`. I have metadata of reports indexed as report title (displayValue), report category (categoryName) etc. The behaviour is due to the `EdgeNgramFilterFactory`, which I need when queries are not enclosed within double quotes. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: You'll have to switch which fields you search against based on whether the query starts with `"` or not. This is a job for your controller.

Comment: I was trying to implement the exact search by following this [link](https://lucidworks.com/post/custom-solr-request-params/). But I am unable to generate the query URL as needed to make the switch query parser work. Can you please check? @MatsLindh

Comment: That's hard to say unless you also include what query URLs you've tried. Does it work if you make the query directly without going through the switch query parser?

Comment: Yes, it works directly without going through the switch query parser. But unable to make it work for the exact search. I am working on it through Solr Admin UI panel. So I would get the generated query URL after I type in a query in my core of Admin UI and I do not know how to enable this switch feature of my request handler while querying in the Admin UI. If you could share your personal contact, I would happy to show you my problem exactly.

Comment: URL with exact=true (from above solrconfig details):
http://localhost:8984/solr/synoptics_core/select?q=sale+AND+exact%3Dtrue&fl=displayValue%2C+reportDetailsNameColumn%2C+categoryName%2C+approved%2C+averageRating%2C+lastOneWeekCount%2C+connectorName%2C+score&wt=json&indent=true

Comment: URL with exact=false (default): 
http://localhost:8984/solr/synoptics_core/select?q=sale&fl=displayValue%2C+reportDetailsNameColumn%2C+categoryName%2C+approved%2C+averageRating%2C+lastOneWeekCount%2C+connectorName%2C+score&wt=json&indent=true

Comment: I think you've misunderstood where the `switch` qparser takes it parameter from - `$exact` refers to a URL query parameter, not a "field" in the query itself. `?q=sale&..&exact=true` would be the way to supply `$exact` to the `v` parameter. In your example queries, it'd be possible to just to prefix the field name `text_exact` directly to your query as well.

Comment: I do not want to query using the field name as prefix, as I need to parse what the client enters (in the search form of the app). I cannot expect them to type the field prefix while querying. That being said, if `$exact` refers to a URL parameter, then how do I generate the required query to trigger the switch qparser using the edismax query parser in the solrconfig.xml?

Comment: As mentioned, you append `&exact=true` to your query string. Your configuration uses `$exact`, which refers to the value supplied as part of the query string.

Comment: I have appended `&exact=true` to the query URL and it is giving results but I haven't found matching documents even with `&exact=true` parameter. The query `"sale"` is matching against `Sales` again. Is there something wrong in the schema definition? Can you have a look at it?. I am thinking the wordt

Comment: You're going to have to debug that issue separately first; does `text_exact:sale` match documents with `Sales`? Use the `Analysis` page under Solr Admin to see exactly how your content is being processed for each step for the field type you've defined.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh `text_exact:sale` isn't giving any match. I am guessing this is because of `text_exact` field definition. Firstly, `text_exact` field is a copyField destination for every other source text field/s (among these there are multivalued fields). Secondly, the analysis page is giving results as expected from the schema definition. But when I search for `text_exact:sale`, there are no results.
Also, can you please confirm the correctness of the switch query filter condition in the request handler above? Especially this part `case.true="text_ex:$q"`. 
No data in text_ex, I suppose.

Comment: No, that should probably be `text_exact`, but you're going to have to debug why `text_exact:sale` isn't giving any hits. If you're doing analysis and it gives the expected result (??) you should get a hit. If you didn't reindex after changing the definitions, you'll have to do that.

Comment: Here text_ex is the field and text_exact is the field type. Can you now clarify if this is correct?...i.e. `"text_ex:$q"` ?... I will try reindexing again

Comment: Ah, in that case, I meant `text_ex` in your test with `sale` above (and that you said it's a destination for copy fields). It's hard to keep track of these names across questions, sorry. You don't query a field type, just a field.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it's hard to keep track of names. By the way, I have tried querying for `market` after reindexing and I did not get results. But, when I tried querying normally (without double quotes), there were reports having only `market` terms (which are expected to be returned when one does the exact search). Exact search query URL. Please check.
[link](http://localhost:8984/solr/synoptics_core/select?q=sale&exact=true&wt=json&indent=true&debugQuery=true) 
`"filter_queries":["{!switch case.false='*:*' case.true='text_ex:$q' v=$exact}"],
    "parsed_filter_queries":["text_ex:q"]`

Comment: Also, I am thinking if this exact search could be achieved in this way also, as the issue described in the link is exactly what is needed from my client too. Please have a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344740/solr-exact-match-regarding-words-number). Thing is, I have tried this method (CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory) but I solr loading error occurred when I restarted. Can you throw some light on this _prefix_ and _suffix_ method as described in the link?

Comment: I have added certain details in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931921/solr-exact-match-results-not-matching), which is an extension of our conversation we had above. Can you please check?